# ImageSX and ImageSY supplied argument is not a valid Image resource

Tags: php, function, gd, thumbnails

I am having difficulty understanding the problem with this function and code included.

All intensive purposes I can tell it should work no problem at all.

I am running GD library 2.034 and this is the code I am exectuing:

```
function createthumb($name,$filename,$new_w,$new_h){
$system=explode('.',$name); 
if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/',$system[1])){ 
    $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
} 
if (preg_match('/png/',$system[1])){ 
    $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($name); 
}

//sizing 
$old_x=imageSX($src_img); 
$old_y=imageSY($src_img); 
if ($old_x > $old_y) { 
    $thumb_w=$new_w; 
    $thumb_h=$old_y*($new_h/$old_x); 
} 
if ($old_x < $old_y) { 
    $thumb_w=$old_x*($new_w/$old_y); 
    $thumb_h=$new_h; 
} 
if ($old_x == $old_y) { 
    $thumb_w=$new_w; $thumb_h=$new_h; 
}

//keep colours 
$dst_img=ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h); 
imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);

//rebuild image 
if (preg_match("/png/",$system[1])) { 
    imagepng($dst_img,$filename); 
} 
else { 
    imagejpeg($dst_img,$filename); 
} 
imagedestroy($dst_img); 
imagedestroy($src_img); 
}
```

Then it is executed with this:

```
$filenameresize = strtolower($_FILES['pic']['name']);
$mkfilename = time() . strrchr($filenameresize, '.');
$newfilename = $imagepath . $mkfilename;
createthumb($newfilename, $imagepath . "/thumbs/tn_" . $mkfilename,100,100);
```

echoing

```
$newfilename
```

gives the name of it if it is echoed BEFORE the createthumb function but does not produce if echoed afterwards.

What have I missed?

Comment: The error message speaks about 'no valid image resource'. Maybe a capital letter in the file extension? Then you will never go to the 'imagecreatefrom...' function, since the check is on lowercase extensions only.

Comment: thats an idea, strtolower here i come!

Comment: edited question to reflect changes that didnt work, plus i checked the filename before and after both are all lowercase. I am thinking this might help? $dimensions = getimagesize($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I fixed it!

Here is the solution.

The problem was in the collection of the file type codewise and the preg matching wasn't getting it right.

I added these lines:

```
list($old_x, $old_y, $type) = getimagesize($name);
switch ($type)
 {
case 1:   //   gif -> jpg
  $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($name);
break;

case 2:   //   jpeg -> jpg
  $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($name); 
break;

case 3:  //   png -> jpg
  $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($name);
break;
}
```

and removed these lines:

```
$system=explode('.',$name); 
if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/',$system[1])){ 
  $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
} 
if (preg_match('/png/',$system[1])){ 
  $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($name); 
}

$old_x=imageSX($src_img); 
$old_y=imageSY($src_img);
```

Hope this will help some of you.

Comment: Good example of why not to use file extensions to determine file type. To increase readability, change your `case` values to use the IMAGETYPE_XXX contants, so IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, and IMAGETYPE_PNG in your example. [See documentation on related exif_imagetype function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php#refsect1-function.exif-imagetype-constants) for details on the possible return values of the image type and the predefined constants.